# Determining the sign of a function containing ratio

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, mathematica

## Problem

We want to know for which values of $x,y,z,w$ the function $\sigma$ is positive or negative:

\begin{equation}
\sigma = \frac{A}{A^2-B^2},
\end{equation}

where
\begin{eqnarray}
A & = & (z-w)^2(x+y)^2 + (z^2-y-2zw)^2(w^2-x)+(z^2+x-2zw)^2(w^2+y)\\
B^2 & = & 4(z^2-y-2zw)^2(z^2+x-2zw)^2(x-w^2)(w^2+y).
\end{eqnarray}
All of $x,y,z,w$ are positive real constants. Furthermore, we know that

\begin{eqnarray}
w^2 & < & x\\
(z-w)^2 & < & w^2+y \quad \Rightarrow\\
z^2-2zw & < & y.
\end{eqnarray}

## My Attempt

I begin by noting that the middle term in $A$ is the only negative one:
\begin{eqnarray}
A & = & \underbrace{(z-w)^2(x+y)^2}_{>0} + \underbrace{(z^2-y-2zw)^2}_{>0}\underbrace{(w^2-x)}_{<0}+\underbrace{(z^2+x-2zw)^2(w^2+y)}_{>0}\\
B^2 & > & 0.
\end{eqnarray}
We can divide the problem into the following steps

1. find for which values the middle term dominates A
2. find for which values the magnitude of $|A|$ is greater/less than $|B|$.

Step 1 gives the sign of the nominator, step 2 the denominator. The combination of these steps solves the problem.
I tried to solve this both by hand and with Mathematica, but I really cant seem to implement it correctly in Mathematica.